# Remove objects on disconnect socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm using Nodejs and Socket.io.  When the client connects, new JavaScript objects are created.

Do these objects just linger forever? Should they be deleted or removed when the client disconnects? Is it even possible to remove an object? I  know delete won't work...

Thanks - I guess this is more of a general question and any suggestions would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you don't cleanup, then yes, they will stay there forever since I assume you are making them global.

You should cleanup once a user disconnects by binding to the `disconnect` event listener:

```
var clients = {}
sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  clients[socket.id] = socket;

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    delete clients[socket.id];
  });
});
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I assume I can use the same method for 'clients' to keep track of other objects as well? There are several other objects outside of the 'socket' functionality that are created.

Comment: jup! What some people do, they add the objects inside the "socket" variable, and it gets destroyed automatically. `socket.data = "foo"` and then the clients just has a id to that socket.

Comment: I don't know why, but `delete clients[socket.id];` sometimes just doesn't work. From my research it seems a socket.io issue...

Comment: @ christian yup i too had that problem....grrrrr ....i finally used 'sync disconnect on unload' : true in io.connect (client side) and somehow it worked

Comment: `delete` is not allowed in `strict mode` is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: What if I don't explicitly store the sockets anywhere? Does it still need to be cleaned up? I am wondering if I should do something like `io.remove(socket)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   socket.on('disconnect', disc => {
    console.log("disconnect");
    console.log(socket.id);
    console.log(rects);
    console.log(rects.indexOf(id));
      let index = rects.indexOf(id);
      rects.splice(index, 1);
      socket.broadcast.emit("discon", id);  
   });
```

Comment: Can you add some details about your solution? Code only answers are not very helpful .