# Destroying a session in Node/Express/Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for a few days, and I just don't understand it. I want to kill my session, when I leave the webpage, but the exception I'm getting (which crashes the server) is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/server.js:46:20)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at Socket.emit (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:128:10)
at Socket.onclose (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:425:8)
at Client.onclose (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:232:24)
at emitTwo (events.js:92:20)
at Socket.emit (events.js:172:7)
at Socket.onClose (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/lib/socket .js:304:10)
at WebSocket.g (events.js:260:16)
```

My connection with disconnect:

```
    // create socket.io connection
    io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    if(sess != null) {
        list.push(sess);
    }

    if(list != null) {
        for(var i = 0; i <= list.length; i++) {
            //console.log("User with session id connected: " +sess['sesid']);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(sess['sesid']) + " CONNECTED");
        }
    }

 socket.on('disconnect', function(req){
        req.session.destroy(sess.sesid);
        //destroy session
        console.log('session killed');
    });
```

Anyone got a clue on how to do this easier? I'm pretty much just adding each new connection into a list of sessions where I save the sessionID and in the future a 'username' to differentiate current online users, to then remove the use when they disconnect.

Comment: Have you tried just setting the object to `null`?

Comment: Not yet, but the thing is the list has to keep all the current online users listed. so setting the list to null would remove everything right?

Comment: Yes, but it is saying your `session` object is undefined. What you're saying at the bottom of your post sounds right, you should likely remove them individually when they disconnect in the `disconnect` event

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to do, but as soon as I call for the req.session.destroy() it then says destroy() is undefined, which I find odd.

Comment: socket.io documentation is pretty scarce, did you see that function somewhere? You'll have to use something else to remove the user from the list I'd imagine

Comment: the session.destroy() function is a part of express-session. I tried setting the list to null when I dispose of a session (for testing) and then if a new item should be set to be added into the list it then crashes saying it can't read property type null from list. as expected

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918203/remove-objects-on-disconnect-socket-io and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463447/socket-io-disconnect-client-by-id as that might be helpful

Comment: @pay thanks, it seemed to have fixed it somehow. I think instead of sessions, I'll use the ID the client gives the server automatically. Seeing as I don't need to save any settings/anything the user sets up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

thanks to pay (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1438893/pay) finding these 2 handy links to help, I've chosen to use the clientid and just removing that from the list of connected sockets.

[Socket.io disconnect client by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463447/socket-io-disconnect-client-by-id)

and

[Remove objects on disconnect socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918203/remove-objects-on-disconnect-socket-io)